# How to hide amazon ads in unity

Tags: ios, amazon-advertising-api

So I integrated amazon mobile ads into my unity/ios project. I have it all working to where I hide the ads every time a scene changes. Every time I open a scene, the ad shows. So it's all working fine except when you change scenes really quickly. I don't want ads in the main game as it obstructs the view of the users. Every time you get to the retry scene, if you quickly switch from that scene right before an ad loads, that ad will get stuck on the next scene which makes another ad show on top of it. Every time a scene changes it should be hiding the ad not matter how fast you change scenes. Is there any way to make sure it hides the ad if an ad is shown? I'm using the code below:

```
void Start() {
    mobileAds = AmazonMobileAdsImpl.Instance;
    ApplicationKey key = new ApplicationKey();
    key.StringValue = iosKey;
    mobileAds.SetApplicationKey(key);

    ShouldEnable enable = new ShouldEnable();
    enable.BooleanValue = true;
    mobileAds.EnableTesting(enable);
    mobileAds.EnableLogging(enable);

    Placement placement = new Placement();
    placement.Dock = Dock.BOTTOM;
    placement.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.CENTER;
    placement.AdFit = AdFit.FIT_AD_SIZE;
    response = mobileAds.CreateFloatingBannerAd(placement);
    string adType = response.AdType.ToString();
    long identifer = response.Identifier;

    newResponse = mobileAds.LoadAndShowFloatingBannerAd(response);
    bool loadingStarted = newResponse.BooleanValue;
}


void OnDestroy() {
    mobileAds.CloseFloatingBannerAd(response);
    response = null;
    mobileAds = null;
    newResponse = null;
}
```

Comment: Maybe this is a dumb question, but why integrate with an ad service just to hide the ads? Or is there more to this?

Comment: We just want to hide ads during the game but show the ads on all of the other scenes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The close ad API

```
 mobileAds.CloseFloatingBannerAd(response);
```

will only work if the ad is already loaded. You need to register for the ad loaded event. If the scene is destroyed, then you would close the ad when the ad loaded event tiggers.

You can register for `AdLoaded` event as follows, [Documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/earn/mobile-ads/unity/mobile-ads-plugin-methods-and-events-for-unity)

```
    using com.amazon.mas.cpt.ads;

    bool sceneDestroyed = false;  //tracks if scene is destroyed



    //Obtain object used to interact with the plugin
    IAmazonMobileAds mobileAds = AmazonMobileAdsImpl.Instance;


    // Define event handler
    private void EventHandler(Ad args)
    {
       if (sceneDestroyed)
       {
            mobileAds.CloseFloatingBannerAd(response);
       }
       else
       {
           //Do some other job
       }
    }

    //Register for an event
    mobileAds.AddAdLoadedListener(EventHandler);

    void OnDestroy() 
    {
                sceneDestroyed = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When did you download the Unity Plugin? There were some issues in an early version of the plugin that this sounds like (the whole, one ad loading over top of another thing). If you have not updated it recently, try downloading the latest version from Amazon and see if the issue still occurs.

Comment: I did download it a week ago so it should be current unless they just released one.